# How do I mock user input in the clap library for Rust?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I am currently building a Rust CLI with clap. Does anyone have any pointers as to how I can mock/mimic user input so I can write my tests?

Comment: [`assert_cmd::Command::cargo_bin(...)`](https://docs.rs/assert_cmd/latest/assert_cmd/) -- and read [this](https://docs.rs/assert_cmd/latest/assert_cmd/macro.crate_name.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`Parser::try_parse_from()`](https://docs.rs/clap/4/clap/trait.Parser.html#method.try_parse_from) (or, if you are not using a `derive(Parser)`, [`Command::try_get_matches_from()`](https://docs.rs/clap/4/clap/builder/struct.Command.html#method.try_get_matches_from)). These functions accepts an iterator of strings instead of consulting the process arguments, so you can pass in any strings you want to test with. It returns a `Result`, so that you can write tests for both success and parse errors.

(This answer applies to `clap` version 4.0. Older versions have significantly different type and function names, but still have this capability.)

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, would you change your answer if I was indeed using derive(Parser)?

Comment: @MichaelChan Sorry, my answer was unclearly phrased. Use `Parser::try_parse_from()` if you are using `derive(Parser)`, and `Command::try_get_matches_from()` if you are not.

Comment: Grateful for all the help!!